# Issue with model binding enums with Json.NET ValueProviderFactory

Tags: c#, json.net, model-binding

I'm trying to use **Json.NET** as my default serializer/deserializer in an ASP.NET MVC5 environment. I already use it to serialize my JsonResult. This works fine. But I'm having issues on using it as my **ValueProviderFactory**.

I have made some tests with complex objects and everything works, except for enumerators on deeper levels on my model (not direct root level properties). 
Like in the code below:

```cs
public class MyModel
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    public MyEnum FirstLevelEnum { get; set; }

    public MyDetailModel Detail { get; set; }
}

public class MyDetailModel
{
     public string Property1 { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<MyEnum> DeeperLevelEnumList { get; set; }
}

public enum MyEnum
{
     Enumerated1,
     Enumerated2
}
```

If I deserialize an object like **MyModel**, all properties will bind correctly, except for the items inside the **DeeperLevelEnumList**, which will turn to the default value **0**.

Back in time, I used to also have a CustomModelBinder, to surpass issues with enums in MVC2~3. I noticed that in MVC5 that is no longer a problem and using the MVC serializer with all the default behaviors works fine (except for really large JSON, which is one of the reasons to use Json.NET).

I compared, side by side, the results in the Dictionary of objects that are generated after the deserialization and they are the same, in both cases, the DeeperLevelEnumList brings the correct value. But, when the ModelBinder **GetPropertyValue** method is called, with MVC deserializer, the bind is correctly made and with Json.Net it's not.

Am I missing something? I really looked into this on many posts and threads and didn't find an answer.

Comment: Json.NET may not know how to deserialize to an interface. Try changing `DeeperEnumLevelList`'s type to some concrete implementation.

Comment: The IEnumerable was just an example like the real scenario, the same object is used to map from an entity. But I found some others issues, like Nullable enum that doesn't map either.